# Laravel - ordering posts by date and get them with pagination

Tags: laravel

I was wondering how can I take posts from the database ordered from the latest to the oldest but with pagination.

This is my current code:

```
        return view('index', [
            'featured' => Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first(),
            'posts' => Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(6)->get(),
        ]);
```

So, I am taking the latest post as "featured" and for the rest of the posts I want to skip first (because it is already taken as "featured" one) and take others from the latest to the oldest but with pagination.

**EDIT**

If someone need this later this piece of code worked for me

```
        $featured = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('id', '!=', $featured->id)->paginate(2);
        return view('index', [
              'featured' => $featured,
              'posts' => $posts,
        ]);
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem? These queries look fine.

Comment: These ones look fine but when I try for example 'posts' => Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(6)->get()->paginate(6), or something like that then it throws error. I am asking how could I modify this line so I get ordered paginated request :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
return view('index', [
            'featured' => Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first(),
            'posts' => Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where(id, '!=', 1)->paginate(6),
        ]);
```

Comment: This will break as soon as there is a second page...

Answer (score 0):

To display them and order them only by created_at

this code below worked for me:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```